# How can I bind the value of a field to a label in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is what I tried. Note that I removed parts of the XAML to make the question shorter but I tested it out by setting detailx.text in my cs and when I do it that way it displays XXXX:

```
<Frame x:Class="Japanese.PhrasesFrame">
    <StackLayout x:Name="phrasesFrameStackLayout" >
        <Grid x:Name="phraseGrid">
            <Grid x:Name="wordGrid" >
                <Grid x:Name="detailGrid">
                   <Label x:Name="detail1" Text="{Binding English}" XAlign="Center" />
                   <Label x:Name="detailx" XAlign="Center" />
```

In my CS I have

```
    public PhrasesFrame()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        correctButton.Clicked += correctButtonClicked;
        resetButton.Clicked += resetButtonClicked;
        SetBindings();
        wordGrid.BindingContext = AS.phrase;
    }
```

In a method I have this:

```
public partial class PhrasesFrame : Frame
{
    Random rand = new Random();

    public PhrasesFrame()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        wordGrid.BindingContext = AS.phrase;
        AS.phrase = new PSCViewModel() { English = "abcd" };
        this.detailx.Text = "XXXX";
    }
```

My problem is that when I used Binding English then the label never shows the text `abcd` but I do see the `XXXX`

Can someone tell me if I am missing something obvious.  I tried everything but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the order, like this:

```
AS.phrase = new PSCViewModel() { English = "abcd" };
wordGrid.BindingContext = AS.phrase;
```

Whenever you set the `BindingContext` at that moment it is applied, as is. If you make changes afterwards, you can, but you need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event to fire off a signal to the UI indicating which property has changed. Only then will it be update in the UI.

Comment: Yes this seems to be the problem and doing what you did makes it work. I have some question about INotifyPropertyChanged but will make that into another questions.  Will accept your answer in 8 minutes.

Comment: BTW you have a very good blog !  Just saw it after looking at your profile

Comment: Thank you! Also check out my YouTube channel for even more clear instructions and if you need anything else don't hesitate to reach out to me directly.